# Material Desing tooltip focus on element using kerborad tab

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have given tooltip in `md-input-container`

```html
<div flex="100" flex-gt-sm="25">
    <md-input-container  class="md-block">
        <label>College/Institute Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="institutename" ng-model="GeneralInfo.collegename" md-maxlength="50" maxlength="50" required>
        <div ng-messages="GeneralInfoForm.institutename.$error">
            <div ng-message="required">College/Institute Name is required.</div>
        </div>
        <md-tooltip>College Name</md-tooltip>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

It shows only when I mouse over the tooltip. when I press tab, it does not show. focus on a tab is not working.

Comment: That's expected behaviour. What do you expect?

Comment: @Edric when I press tab , tool-tip should work

Answer (score 0):

That is intentional behaviour. See the gif below (I'm using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key):

[image: Tabbing on tooltip]

Comment: Yeh, it working on button. but its not working on `md-input-container` :( as I mentioned above